# too many redirection after redirect forced https by code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https

I have a website application in asp.net mvc.
To authenticate a user, I use a `Microsoft SSO authenticate`.

The iis configuration have ssl certificate.

I have the following problem :
in chrome, when I put this URL: https://mydomain/myapplication

auto redirect to : `https://loginmicrosoft.....`

to come back on my website , my url is passed in http without secure.

If I refresh this url, I come back with https.

now, I tested this code in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

With this, I have too many redirect.

do you have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you traced the redirects through a tool like Fiddler? Could there be something else that is doing the exact opposite elsewhere in the code so it bounces between the two forever? (Also, I recommend using rewrite rules in the web.config to handle the likes of this, it's more easily changed between local and live installations, for one thing).

Comment: I add logs in this method, before et inside the redirect and i have something like this :`date=22/09/2017 10:46:30 URL = http://xxx.xxx.com/testsso URL REFERRER = 
date=22/09/2017 10:46:30 REDIRECT TO =https://xxx.xxx.com/testsso
date=22/09/2017 10:46:31 URL = http://xxx.xxx.com/testsso URL REFERRER = 
date=22/09/2017 10:46:31 REDIRECT TO =https://xxx.xxx.com/testsso
date=22/09/2017 10:46:32 URL = http://xxx.xxx.com/testsso URL REFERRER = 
date=22/09/2017 10:46:32 REDIRECT TO =https://xxx.xxx.com/testsso`

Comment: Did you get a Fiddler trace? Anyway those logs back up my guess (but I can't do more than make an educated guess) that there's something else in the application as a whole (in the routing, in the web config, in the controller that gets hit are all possibilities) that dose the opposite redirect, so then that hits this code again, then that other bit of code is hit again, and so on forever (or until the browser refuses to do more and complains "too many redirects).

Comment: i'm going to try to get fiddler trace but the application is a test application. I created an empty project only with SSO. there are nothing else in application.